# Alarm Manager Not Working When Device Goes OFF

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to keep running **Alarm Manager** at given time interval.

I implement it but doesn't work in proper time period. Sometime its call two times and sometime not call at time of interval.

I used **RTC** and  **RTC_WAKEUP** and i also want to know what is the meaning of this filed

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestBroadCastReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_start)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 2000*60, pi);
                Log.d("ALARM MANAGER", "Start Alarm Manager... At " + new Date());
            }
        });

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_stop)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                alarmManager.cancel(pi);
                Log.d("ALARM MANAGER", "Stop Alarm Manager...");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AlarmBroadCastReceiver.java**

```
public class TestBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e("ALARM MANAGER", "BROADCAST RECEIVER : " + new Date());

    }
}
```

**Log**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html has an example of BroadcastReceiver, which listens for device awakening. 
Starting service from that receiver and schedule next alarm in it. 
I've used SharedPreferences for storing next alarm time and starting the same service for handling alarm and scheduling a new one after device boot by passing different keys in start Intent.
As documentation says, RTC won't wake you phone if it is blocked, but RTC_WAKEUP will.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want to keep continue my Alarm Manager either device is in sleep or running mode until user not stop it.

Comment: Alarm manager is running in sleep mode - that is why there is RTC_WAKEUP - this flag allow to wake phone up. All alarm is cancelled if device is turned off.

Comment: Ya i know that cancel all alarm at device shutdown time but why we use RTC, RTC_EAKEUP this type of constant

Comment: The difference between two of those is behaviour while device is in sleep mode - RTC_WAKEUP will awake device, but RTC won't. RTC will be fired later, when device is unlocked.